# fstrim trimming all the free space after reboot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, trim

I just upgraded to a SSD. Performance has been great.

However, after every reboot, when I do a fstrim to the partitions, it will trim all the free space. And as I understand, trimming writes to all the free space that that it is available. Not sure if relevant, but I use full disk encryption (/boot included).

As the life of the SSD can be reduced dramatically with frequent writes, I'm worried about this trimming.

Here are the logs I keep on every trim:

```
Jul 30 13:46:00 /: 478.6 MiB (501862400 bytes) trimmed
Jul 31 13:22:26 /: 347.8 GiB (373409230848 bytes) trimmed
Jul 31 13:25:32 /: 194.3 MiB (203710464 bytes) trimmed
Jul 31 13:25:40 /: 19.2 MiB (20111360 bytes) trimmed
Aug 02 14:08:06 /: 345.9 GiB (371398463488 bytes) trimmed
Aug 02 22:21:36 /: 56.9 GiB (61047971840 bytes) trimmed
Aug 02 22:31:27 /: 347.7 MiB (364560384 bytes) trimmed
Aug 02 22:31:43 /: 127 MiB (133144576 bytes) trimmed
Aug 02 22:33:01 /: 243 MiB (254767104 bytes) trimmed
Aug 03 06:58:47 /: 1 GiB (1080602624 bytes) trimmed
Aug 03 10:00:02 /: 2.4 GiB (2526216192 bytes) trimmed
Aug 03 11:42:14 /: 341 GiB (366146318336 bytes) trimmed
Aug 03 16:00:01 /: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
Aug 03 16:33:53 /: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
Aug 03 16:48:43 /: 341 GiB (366074740736 bytes) trimmed
Aug 03 16:50:13 /: 1.2 GiB (1297809408 bytes) trimmed
Aug 03 16:53:31 /: 341 GiB (366074695680 bytes) trimmed
Aug 03 17:07:55 /: 340.9 GiB (366066126848 bytes) trimmed
Aug 05 22:00:13 /: 341 GiB (366073069568 bytes) trimmed
Aug 05 22:07:22 /: 1.2 GiB (1261793280 bytes) trimmed
Aug 06 07:41:50 /: 1.4 GiB (1522991104 bytes) trimmed
Aug 06 10:00:11 /: 341 GiB (366068740096 bytes) trimmed
```

As you can see, the trimming after the computer has been turned on is ~340GiB, while the trimming on normal usage is just about 1GiB.

Should I be worried that this will wear out my SSD? Should I not trim?

Answer (score 1):

There is a misconception. Trimming does not cause extra writes, it **decreases** them.

A SSD, or rather its NAND, has two notions of "blocks" of which one is actually called *block* (usually something 128k to 512k), and the other one that is much closer to what you mean when you talk of "block" in terms of your filesystem is called *page* (usually something around 4k). You can *write* out a complete page at a time, just as you would on an old harddisk, no problem. Things just work as expected.

However, you cannot *overwrite* a page, they are write-once. You can thereafter only *erase* it, making it once-writable again. This is what counts towards the NAND's lifetime. The problem is just... in reality you *cannot* erase pages. You can only erase *blocks* (i.e. clusters of 32-64 pages at a time).

This means that when you overwrite a page ("block" in terms of filesystem), the controller has to:

1. read in the complete block
2. if a "virgin" or already erased block exists, use that one
3. otherwise *clear* the same block
4. write out the complete block, having accordingly modified the contents of the overwritten page
5. do some unspecified "magic" so the erase cycles are somewhat evenly distributed over all blocks, preventing premature death

This is somewhat simplified, but the principle is like that. A *smart* controller might do something slightly different (e.g. remap pages logically, fill all pages until none are left, and somehow "remember" which ones are good and which ones are stale, etc, etc), but in principle the workflow is as outlined above.

This is a problem insofar as small writes are a common thing, so soon you have every block on your disk having been written to at least once. Now what can the controller do? Not much. It doesn't really know what the filesystem is doing or what is expected, so it has to work on the most conservative assumption. That is, everything and anything that was once written must be preserved.

TRIM solves this problem. It tells the controller that a such-and-such large range *is not being used*, so the controller can as well discard it. It doesn't write anything. If at all, it will only erase blocks (though, only once, not every time).
Since you told the controller that you aren't using that data, it can risk to throw it away without harm. Now suddenly there are writeable blocks available again without the need of copying around data and repeatedly erasing blocks. Which not only makes writes *faster* but also decreases the number of erases that must happen.

Answer (score 0):

`fstrim` seems to release *all* free space of a partition, not only the space released since the last invocation of `fstrim`. See also [this posting](https://superuser.com/questions/1477772).