# Why does fstrim trim more space than df reports as available

Tags: linux, ssd, trim

I'm using KUbuntu 18.04 with 4.15.0-58-generic and a SanDisk SD8SBAT256G1122 SSD

When doing a `sudo fstrim -av` I see

```
/opt:   63.1 GiB (67707994112 bytes) trimmed
/home:  68   GiB (72999329792 bytes) trimmed
/:      18.9 GiB (20238721024 bytes) trimmed
```

while a `df` shows

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       30832548 11061016  18182284  38% /
/dev/sda5       82045336 10745788  67088860  14% /home
/dev/sda6       92853216 26732128  61361368  31% /opt
```

When I convert all into 1k blocks I get

```
              trim        free    trim-free       %
  /       19764376    18182284      1582092     8.7%
  /home   71288408    67088860      4199548     6.3%
  /opt    66121088    61361368      4759720     7.7%
```

and thus see that the `fstrim` trimmed ~8% more space than `df` shows
as available.

How comes ?
Does `fstrim` some double trimming, are some areas released twice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most file systems allow an option to reserve a portion of the space for adminstrative use - this is to make sure, that a file system that is full in the sense of not allowing any more addition of payload data still has enough blocks to allow the superuser to clean it up (e.g. move things around). This space is typically between 5 and 10% and normally unused, so a candidate for trimming.

Comment: That's it. When I recalculate the free space from partition size (from `fdisk`) and the _used size_ (from `df`) it is larger. And now comes out to be slightly less than the _trim size_ (from `fstrim`). This difference is most likely due to file system meta data which is not counted as _used size_.